# You don't sometimes hate them

Tags: adverbs

This sentence is from "English File" by Clive Oxenden, and Christina Latham-Koenig. I am confused by their use of "sometimes". I remember being told by a native speaker that it's not used between verbs after "not" or "doesn't". The sentence says "you don't sometimes hate them". Should I really avoid this use?

> Frankly, if you have lived together all your life and you don't sometimes hate them, you haven't been paying attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native speaker probably warned you about sentences such as:

> *I don't sometimes go to the store.
>
> *Jessica is not sometimes annoying.

For declarative sentences, this is generally a valid objection. In addition to sounding very unnatural, it's also not clear what you're trying to say - do you go to the store more often than *sometimes*, or less often? You could argue whether it's grammatical or not, but it's a moot point when the sentence is nonsensical.

However, it's not a rule that you should never negate *sometimes*. For example, it's perfectly valid to do so in questions:

> Don't you sometimes want to go home?

Your example is a part of a conditional clause of a conditional sentence (***if**... you don't sometimes hate them*). Those - aside from the lack of inversion - tend to behave a little like questions grammatically. For example, you can use *ever* in a conditional clause:

> If you ever find yourself in trouble, call me.

while you wouldn't use it in a declarative sentence:

> *I ever find myself in trouble.

This "question-like" behavior is also why your example sentence works, while a declarative **I don't sometimes hate them* doesn't.

Comment: Footnote: there's also a distinction between negating *sometimes* and applying *sometimes* to a negative, which is valid (eg. *I don't go to the store sometimes* - ie. I usually go to the store, but sometimes I do not). Also, there are some edge cases, such as *"He sometimes goes to the store." "Excuse me? I don't **sometimes** go to the store, I go there every day!"*, but I have no clue about the grammar concept involved here.

Comment: But  "Sometimes I don't go to the store"  and "I sometimes don't go to the store"  have the same meaning as "I don't go to the store sometimes - ie. I usually go to the store, but sometimes I do not)". Right?

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes, and those all work, it's just *\*I don't sometimes go to the store* that's the odd one out. All of the three examples in your comment apply *sometimes* to a negative (*I don't go to the store*).

Comment: "I ever find myself in trouble" sounds correct, if slightly archaic and literary to me - the connotation I'm getting from it is a girl saying it while batting her eyelashes at a guy who just rescued her from trouble she just got herself into.

Comment: Do you really mean "imperative", or do you mean something like "affirmative", or "declarative", or possibly "indicative"? "Imperative" refers to commands or requests.

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski, is it the same with "often"? I don't often go to the store?

Comment: @Alan yes, my bad - thanks! Fixed now.

Comment: @AntoniaA *I don't often go to the store* is fine, since you can negate *often* and have it make sense - *not often* has a clear meaning of *less frequently than "often"*. It's *sometimes* (and similar words such as *occasionally*) that don't make sense when negated.

Comment: Could you tell me what other words aren't negated?